# Update sql query with PHP and variables

Tags: php, html, sql, sql-update

When I run this page, its says `You couldnt execute query`. I think there is a syntax problem, but I cannot see the problem.

The variables look fine when I echo them. I added the column names as a code comment. All the columns are `VARCHAR`.

I don't believe it is a connection problem since I can perform `SELECT AND DELETE` operations from other `php` pages.

```
<?php 

$id = $_POST["id"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];

/* Table in the DDBB(all are VARCHAR): CUST_ID  CUST_FORENAME   CUST_PHONE  CUST_SURNAME*/

$query = "UPDATE customers SET CUST_ID='$id',$CUST_FORENAME='$name',
            CUST_PHONE='$phone', CUST_SURNAME='$surname' WHERE CUST_ID=$id";

$result = mysqli_query ($connection,$query)
    or die ("You couldn’t execute query");

echo "<br /><br />User $id has been updated.";

?>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Do not use string concatenation in SQL queries. Use prepared statements.

Comment: Change your `die("You couldn't...")` function to `die(mysqli_error($connection))`, so that you will see the error description.

Comment: put `$id` into quote `'$id'`

Comment: `$CUST_FORENAME='$name'`
? Shouldn't you delete that first character? :), as in
`CUST_FORENAME='$name'`

Comment: did you include the page where the connection is

Comment: why you are updating id `CUST_ID='$id'` and then using same id in where clause `WHERE CUST_ID=$id`?

Comment: This is what return @YeldarKurmangaliyev 

You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '='Mullin', CUST_PHONE='0141-563-2847', CUST_SURNAME='George' WHERE CUST_ID=G' at line 1

Comment: It looks like you are inserting it into database or if it already exists than update it.

Comment: Change `$CUST_FORENAME` to `CUST_FORENAME`

Comment: @AdriánVázquez Yes, other people are right - you have a `$` sign in a SQL query.

Comment: Yes I include the page where the connection is, and also I wont allow to edit the ID in the future, I just want to make it works first

Answer (score 3):

Change your query as follows and it will work

```
$query = "UPDATE customers SET CUST_ID='$id', CUST_FORENAME='$name',
                 CUST_PHONE='$phone', CUST_SURNAME='$surname' WHERE CUST_ID='$id'";
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys, It was just a $ sign in one of the column and put back again quotes in the $id > '$id'.

```
$id = $_POST["id"];
$name = $_POST["name"];
$surname = $_POST["surname"];
$phone = $_POST["phone"];

/*CUST_ID   CUST_FORENAME   CUST_PHONE  CUST_SURNAME*/

$query = "UPDATE customers SET CUST_ID='$id',CUST_FORENAME='$name',
            CUST_PHONE='$phone', CUST_SURNAME='$surname' WHERE CUST_ID='$id'";

$result = mysqli_query ($connection,$query)
    or die(mysqli_error($connection));

echo "<br /><br />User $id has been updated.";

?>
```